# find a point such that the maximum distance to any point in a set of points P is minimized

Tags: algorithm, 2d, graph-theory

Given a set of points in 2d-space P, where Pi = (Xi, Yi),

I need to find a target point T such that the maximum distance to any Pi is minimized.

T does not need to exist in P, and can be defined arbitrarily

Is there an algorithm I can use for this?

Comment: Any or sum will not be the same point.

Comment: I updated the question to get rid of the reference to the approximate solution I was using, since it is irrelevant to the discussion.

Comment: I thought it added value.  A fast estimate.   And a good starting point for an iterative algorithm.

Comment: Some times you get lucky and there is already a .NET implementation out there but I am not finding one.

Answer (score 10):

This is the [smallest circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem).

Comment: yeah, this is basically what I want, except I don't need the radius I just need the center point.

Comment: The wikipedia article contains a linear time algorithm to solve this problem. I highly doubt that not requiring a radius in the output will allow for faster solutions.

Comment: yeah, the paper is hard to read though, you got any pseudocode for the alg?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs507/projects/1998/jacob/problem.html

Think this may be a solution to your problem with pretty good explanation, but it's O(n^2)

Comment: Problem is that the link to the actual algorithm is broken. But a cool live graph to represent the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't proved it, but i think the solution is just:

(min(Xi) + max(Xi)) / 2, (min(Yi) + max(Yi))/2)

Comment: actually this is an approximation.

imagine a square around the smallest circle, the maximum amount the approximation can be out, is the distance from the corner of the square to the circle.